Spring 5 wait until a late initialized bean is available, depends-on and order have not helped
How to wait until bean "allAppConfigs" is initialized and then initialize bean "pseudoBean1"? For PostConstruct-annotated-Method "populateMap" member "allAppConfigs" is needed with values to fill the map.
I tried depends-on and different orders, reading spring 5 / 6 manual / docs and InitializingBean interface. I think import of resources is done too late. Maybe there is a good solution. Thanks in advance.
About order when Spring injects:

(1) PseudoBean1.setApplicationConfigRegistry(...)
(2) PseudoBean1setAllAppConfigs(...)
(then PostConstruct runs)
(3) PseudoBean2.setAllAppConfigs(...)

spring.xml:
...
<!-- Objects imported as AppConfig.class -->
<import resource="folder/*.xml">

<util:list id="allAppConfigs" value-type="edu.somepackage.models.AppConfig">
    <ref bean="systemAppConfig">
    <ref bean="someAppConfig">
    <ref bean="springAppConfig">    
</util:list>
...

myFrameWork/spring.xml:
<bean id="pseudoBean2" class="PseudoBean2">
    <property name="allAppConfigs" ref="allAppConfigs" />
</bean>

<bean id="pseudoBean1" class="PseudoBean1">
    <property name="applicationConfigRegistry" ref="pseudoBean2" />
</bean>

public class PseudoBean2 {

    private List<AppConfig> allAppConfigs;
    
    public void setAllAppConfigs(List<AppConfig> allAppConfigs) {
        this.allAppConfigs = allAppConfigs;
    }
    
    public List<AppConfig> allAppConfigs() {
        return this.allAppConfigs;
    }
}

public class PseudoBean1 {

    private PseudoBean2 applicationConfigRegistry;

    private Map<String, AppConfigImpl> map = new HashMap<>();

    private List<AppConfig> allAppConfigs = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void setApplicationConfigRegistry(PseudoBean2 applicationConfigRegistry) {
        this.applicationConfigRegistry = applicationConfigRegistry;
    }

    public void setAllAppConfigs(List<AppConfig> allAppConfigs) {
        this.allAppConfigs = allAppConfigs;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void populateMap() {
        int i = 1;
        for(AppConfig config : applicationConfigRegistry.allAppConfigs()) {
            map.put("key" + i, config);
            i++;
        }
    }
}


If I copy your code, the map is populated with no problems.PseudoBean1 relies on PseudoBean2 which in turn relies on allAppConfigs. By the time PseudoBean1 is instantiated, all its dependencies have been created already by the IoC container, since it needs to resolve them first. Therefore, in your @PostContrust method PseudoBean2 already contains the allAppConfigs dependency to populate the map.

If you are configuring the dependencies correctly, you shouldn't have to use any special properties such as depends-on and order for simple use cases such as this.
Spring automatically resolves dependencies and loads them in the correct order for extremely complex applications. If the application context has both XMLs imported, this should work properly. You need to ensure that the application context is importing all the contexts you need.
Furthermore, if this is a web application, spring boot will automatically create a DispatcherServlet with its own servlet context. In this case you would need to ensure the imports make sense with respect to the context hierarchy.
For example, if the root context declares pseudoBean2 but the definition for allAppConfigs is in the servlet context, it will not work as the servlet context is a child of the root context. Therefor, the servlet context will have access to dependencies declared in the root context, but not vice versa.

Thank you. I am not using Spring Boot only Spring (Core).

Answers are right. Sometimes such error happens, because circular bean dependencies exist.
I found solution to listen to ContextRefreshedEvent, then all beans are initialized and I am able to execute a method on this event.
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void method(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    executeAMethod();
}


Therefore the structure you've presented in the question post is not correct. There is no circular dependency in the minimal reproducible example you've provided.
